# Running install mod_dav_svn and can't decipher thread error

Tags: python, linux, apache, module, trace

I am relatively new to Python, and at the same time, am attempting to install mod_dav_svn into my Apache web server. I am looking to get some idea of the scope of the error I'm receiving.

At the command line, I type in 'sudo yum install mod_dav_svn' and receive this output:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in ?
    yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 229, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 104, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()
  File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 339, in doCommands
    self._getTs(needTsRemove)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 101, in _getTs
    self._getTsInfo(remove_only)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/depsolve.py", line 112, in _getTsInfo
    pkgSack = self.pkgSack
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 591, in 
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 434, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 223, in populateSack
    self.doSetup()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 71, in doSetup
    self.ayum.plugins.run('postreposetup')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/yum/plugins.py", line 176, in run
    func(conduitcls(self, self.base, conf, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 181, in postreposetup_hook
    all_urls = FastestMirror(all_urls).get_mirrorlist()
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 333, in get_mirrorlist
    self._poll_mirrors()
  File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/fastestmirror.py", line 376, in _poll_mirrors
    pollThread.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/threading.py", line 416, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread

The only other question I could find with a similar error was this one: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=can%27t+start+new+thread+python, but I'm not sure it has to do with running too many threads since I am the only one using the server, and this is one of the first python commands I have used. Could someone point me in the right direction, or towards some material that may help me troubleshoot the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable yum-fastermirror and you should be able to complete the install.

yum --disableplugin=fastestmirror update

Are you on a virtual machine?

Comment: Actually this solution didn't work, but it did send me down the right path. I am on a Virtual Machine, and I essentially edited /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf, and disabled the plug in there. Great advice though, I would have been lost without it.